# Parsing XML in C without libraries.

Tags: c++, c, xml, algorithm, parsing

Could anyone give me an overview on process of parsing xml in standalone C with only standard libraries.

I am wanting to work on this as practice and because this is a useful project actually.

Most of the examples I see seem to use pointers a lot and also arrays of structures. So any tips or outlines would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you're going to build a tree structure from the data in the file. The problem is essential the front-end of a compiler and the usual compiler texts are the place to begin.

Comment: I write a lot of toy programs, but parsing XML manually is something I never, ever will have the desire to do.

Comment: Do you have any resources on doing this? Or basic implementations I could look at.

Comment: Jonathon, would you say this is a fairly advance topic?

Comment: It is not enormously advanced, but it is a bigish, complicated project that is easy to get wrong.

Comment: As was already mentioned, it's really a big and complicated project which may take considerable time. Have you considered more simple formats such as .ini?

Comment: @sdsd: It's not so much advanced as just pointless. It's the least interesting language to write a parser for (since it's barely a language), and yet it has all of these annoying rules about namespaces, URIs, encodings, and so forth.

Comment: @sdsd:  Nicol has it right.  The first 95% of XML parsing (nested tags and text) is pretty easy.  The last 5% is impossible, made so by a committee that added all kinds of crazy stuff.   And if you can't read it, you won't read real XML documents.    If you only want do the first 95% and read non-conforming XML documents, then it might be fun project for a few evenings.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you would be looking at two different things.  The first would be the high level strategies for accomplishing this.  The second would be the data structures and other language specific implementation details you'd use to get it done.

For the high level part, a good place to start is to study Finite Automata.  They're a very powerful conceptual tool for planning parsing and other heavily state dependent jobs and are readily translated into code.

For the implementation details... well, someone already pointed out tree structures.  XML is basically a tree when you get down to it.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple, you just read in the text and build it into an object tree.

If you had the following simple XML:

```
<A>Hello<B x="1">World</B></A>
<A>Another Object A</A>
```

You could build something like:

```
Obj_1
  Name = "A"
  Text = "Hello"
  --> Obj_2
      Name = "B"
      Text = "World"
      Param_1 (Name = "x", Value = "1")
Obj_3
  Name = "A"
  Text = "Another Object A"
```

With a simple class object like this you could build the tree (I realize you asked about parsing it in regular C, but you also tagged it C++ so my example is in C++):

```
class Obj
{
public:
  struct Param{
    std::string name;
    std::string value;
  };
  std::string      text;
  std::string      name;
  std::list<Param> params;
  std::list<Obj *> children;
};
```

Then you'd want to add some helpers to translate between value strings (which is what XML is) to integers, doubles, bools, etc and to clean up extra whitespace.  You'd probably also want to add some code to get all of the root objects named "XYZ" so you don't have to manually loop through all the time.

This should give you an idea of where to start.  It really isn't that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use existing libraries, you will need to construct XML parser yourself. There's no way you can parse XML by hand efficiently.

I'd advise you to pick up basic concepts on:

1. Regular Expressions
2. DFA/NFA
3. Lexer/Scanner
4. Type of grammars (at least learn Regular Grammars & Context Free Grammars)
5. BNF, EBNF
6. Recursive Descent Parsing

Take this great course for free: https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers

If you are not constrained by time, take this as a learning opportunity.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

scan the xml file and check up to ('>' and !='\n') and start to store the values upto '<'